# How do I create a Tobit model in R?

Tags: r, regression

Fairly new to R, so please bear with me.

I'm hoping to create a model where my outcome variable is only positive -
 number of conversions from Facebook ads.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
| Team            | Opp_Team             | Channel_Market | Week | Thuuz_Rating | Team_EloRating | Opp_Team_EloRating | Divisional | Spend   | Results_Total |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Tampa Bay Buccaneers | Fox_In         | 1    | 46           | 1486           | 1412               | 1          | 4681.63 | 48      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Carolina Panthers    | Fox_In         | 4    | 68           | 1510           | 1604               | 1          | 5373.1  | 45      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Denver Broncos       | Fox_In         | 5    | 66           | 1541           | 1690               | 0          | 5339.04 | 15      |
+-----------------+----------------------+----------------+------+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| Atlanta Falcons | Seattle Seahawks     | Fox_In         | 6    | 68           | 1576           | 1654               | 0          | 6304.21 | 41      |
```

I have installed the AER package and tried this code:

```
library(AER)
nfltobit = tobit(Results_Total ~ Team + Opp_Team + Channel_Market + Week + Spend + Team:Spend + Opp_Team:Spend + Channel_Market:Spend + Week:Spend, left = 0 , right = Inf, data = nfltrain)
```

For some reason I get an error: "unused arguments (left = 0, right = Inf, data = nfltrain)"

Perhaps I'm not approaching this correctly, or the tobit function isn't the correct method. I've tried looking everywhere for a solution, but I'm afraid I'm a bit stuck. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You need to show some data to get the answer you want. Use `dput(head(variable_name))` and give us a few rows to look at and your answer will be more likely to be useful.

Comment: `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 ...` this is a syntax error, so I doubt you've given us the code you actually ran.

Comment: @sconfluentus I edited my post to show a few rows of data. Thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico sorry about that, I edited my post to be more specific. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a Results_Total column in your dataset? I only see Results in the sample you provided.

Comment: If your data is "count", perhaps you could use a glm with Poisson distribution of errors?

Comment: @Z.Lin sorry for the confusion, I changed the column name in the table. Results_Total is the correct variable name in the tobit function

Comment: @RomanLuštrik hi, unfortunately "Results_Total" is not count data. It's possible to get 25.5 conversions for example, if we accounted for multi-channel attribution

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly for me. Have you tried to uninstall the package and install it again? You may be working with an old version. Try this:

```
remove.packages("AER")
install.packages("AER")
```

Then, run again your code. If the problem persists, try to update R. You can use the following code:

```
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
updateR()
```

Cheers!